# How to still call Graph API v1.0 from iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

Yesterday when I created a new app on Facebook I copied much of my code from previous iOS projects regarding Facebook and thought that was going to work as always, but no. The Facebook API has changed. But the thing is that I am still using the old 3.13.0 SDK for iOS, not the new 3.14.0. How come the calls I make goes to the new 2.0 API? Is there any way to call the old one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you created your app after 4/30/2014 there is no way to use API v1.0

Comment: Ok thank you, I thought you still could call the old one if you used the old SDK even if the app was created after April 30th. Well...